# How to intergate google_mobile_ads widget into an existing app

Tags: flutter, google-mobile-ads

I switched from `firebase_admob` into recommended `google_mobile_ads` and now I need to include `AdWidget` into the existing widgets tree.

I made it this way, i.e. I added stack over SingleChildScrollView according to it is shown here https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_admob

But now the content is not scrolling and the bannerAd is showing in the center of the screen (should not in be at the bottom of the screen with padding 10 from the bottom?).

Obviously, it's not what I wanted, how to fix it?

```
body: Stack(
        children: [
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) Message(i, data[i]),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: AdWidget(ad: bannerAd),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  MobileAds.instance.initialize();
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: App()));
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  //Generating a list of data to use in Column
  List<String> data = List.generate(50, (i) => '$i. Priyansu');

  //The method to produce an Ad
  final BannerAd myBanner = BannerAd(
    adUnitId: 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111',
    size: AdSize.banner,
    request: const AdRequest(),
    listener: const BannerAdListener(),
  );

  @override
  void initState() {
    //Initializing the Ad before using it in the widget tree
    myBanner.load();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                  Message (message: data[i]),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 60,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: SizedBox(
              height: myBanner.size.height.toDouble(),
              child: AdWidget(ad: myBanner),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

//Widget to show data in Column
class Message extends StatelessWidget {
  const Message({Key? key, required this.message})
      : super(key: key);
  final String message;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        const SizedBox(
          height: 30,
        ),
        Row(
          children: [
            Text(message, style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 20),),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```